# How to apply evolutions to test database from DatabaseConfigProvider

Tags: playframework, guice, slick, play-slick

I want to test dao (`play 2.6.21, play-slick 3.0.3`):

```
@Singleton
class MyDao @Inject()(@NamedDatabase("default") protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
                             (implicit val sc: ExecutionContext)
  extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  ...

}
```

I place database config for test database in test resources:

```
slick.dbs.default {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
  endpoint = "localhost:12345"
  schema = "my_test_schemma"

  db {
    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://"${slick.dbs.default.endpoint}"/"${slick.dbs.default.schema}""
  }
}
```

In test, I want apply evolutions:

```
class MyDaoSpec extends FlatSpec with GuiceFakeApplicationFactory {

  implicit lazy val app: Application = fakeApplication()

  "dao" should "something" in {

    val conf = app.injector.instanceOf[DatabaseConfigProvider]
    val db = app.injector.instanceOf[Database]
    Evolutions.applyEvolutions(db)

    val dao = app.injector.instanceOf[MyDao]
    //tests...

  }

}
```

But it give me error:

> Guice configuration errors for `instanceOf[Database]`:
>
> 1) No implementation for play.api.db.Database was bound.   while
>   locating play.api.db.Database

So how I can access database and apply evolution to it?

I found, that I need use `EvolutionComponents`, but dont understand how use it

Comment: which play and play-slick versions are you using?

Comment: updated with versions

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984028/how-to-apply-play-evolutions-when-running-tests-in-play-framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was, that I add following dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(evolutions, jdbc)
```

But correct was:

`"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.3",`

There are no special steps for test, just in config:

```
play.evolutions.enabled = true
play.evolutions.autoApply = true
```